# Picture linked to user's profile in user-picture.tpl.php

Tags: theming

D7: In my user-picture.tpl.php template I have the following code:

```
<div class="user-image">
  <?php
    $user = user_load($account->uid);
    print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'square', 'path' => $user->picture->uri));
  ?>
</div>
```

This short snippet sets the default, site wide, for the user picture.

When using views, linking the picture is easy. But when not using views, how can I change this so that the picture is linked to the user's profile?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Load a variable with your theme function (instead of printing it) and the use `l()` with the html key set to true. So, `l($image, '/user/' . $user->uid, array('html' => true)`

Comment: @ChrisRockwell you can post this as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`template_preprocess_user_picture()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7) uses the following code.

```
  $variables ['user_picture'] = '';
  if (variable_get('user_pictures', 0)) {
    $account = $variables['account'];
    if (!empty($account->picture)) {
      if (is_numeric($account->picture)) {
        $account->picture = file_load($account->picture);
      }
      if (!empty($account->picture->uri)) {
        $filepath = $account->picture->uri;
      }
    }
    elseif (variable_get('user_picture_default', '')) {
      $filepath = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    }
    if (isset($filepath)) {
      $alt = t("@user's picture", array('@user' => format_username($account)));
      if (module_exists('image') && file_valid_uri($filepath) && $style = variable_get('user_picture_style', '')) {
        $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => $style, 'path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt));
      }
      else {
        $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image', array('path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt));
      }
      if (!empty($account->uid) && user_access('access user profiles')) {
        $attributes = array('attributes' => array('title' => t('View user profile.')), 'html' => TRUE);
        $variables['user_picture'] = l($variables ['user_picture'], "user/$account->uid", $attributes);
      }
    }
  }
```

Assuming you just want to use a specific image style for the image, and hard code it in your theme, I would use the following code for `mytheme_preprocess_user_picture()`. (Replace `mytheme` with the short name of the theme.)

```
  $variables ['user_picture'] = '';
  if (variable_get('user_pictures', 0)) {
    $account = $variables['account'];
    if (!empty($account->picture)) {
      if (is_numeric($account->picture)) {
        $account->picture = file_load($account->picture);
      }
      if (!empty($account->picture->uri)) {
        $filepath = $account->picture->uri;
      }
    }
    elseif (variable_get('user_picture_default', '')) {
      $filepath = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    }
    if (isset($filepath)) {
      $alt = t("@user's picture", array('@user' => format_username($account)));
      if (module_exists('image') && file_valid_uri($filepath)) {
        $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'square', 'path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt));
      }
      else {
        $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image', array('path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt));
      }
      if (!empty($account->uid) && user_access('access user profiles')) {
        $attributes = array('attributes' => array('title' => t('View user profile.')), 'html' => TRUE);
        $variables['user_picture'] = l($variables ['user_picture'], "user/$account->uid", $attributes);
      }
    }
  }
```

Doing so, the template file would just need to print `$user_picture`.

Keep in mind that the image style used for the user image is contained in a Drupal variable. I would investigate on how to change that variable for the theme you are using, even though you would then need to change it back for the other themes, in the case your theme is not anymore the active one.

Comment: Thank you. I can't get it to work. It's strange because this is straight out of the book. I put the preprocessor in my template.tpl.php file and opened it with: "function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_picture(&$vars) {" it doesn't even apply the image style. The Image module is enabled. The base theme is Bartik. Any idea? :)

Comment: Preprocess functions go in template.php.

Comment: Yes, my mistake in my previous comment. It's in template.php

Comment: If you are editing an enabled theme, Drupal will not notice there are new preprocess or alter hooks. For the rest, the code should work because is the same code used by Drupal.

Comment: I use a sub-theme (copy of Bartik) that I have renamed and placed in my sites/all/themes directory. I have noticed however that the pre-processor works on some pictures but not on others. There may be a module taking control at some point (I am thinking of privatemsg since it mainly doesn't work on any of the pics there.)